# Closing toastr in webdriver

Tags: javascript, automation, webdriver, webdriver-io, toastr

*UI automation testing*
I have toast message all around my app, sometimes I get multiple toasts, which blocks clicking on other parts of the app. meaning I have to close them before I can interact with other buttons. 
I wrote an if else statement to close them. when there is only one it works. when there are more than 2 toasts it fails.

- I am using JS and Node js
- Using Webdriverio and Mocha
- This is the toastr library https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Can someone tell me what am I missing?

```js
closeToastMessage() {
  let close_toast = $$('.toast-close-button');
  const closeToasts = $$('.toast-close-button');
  let toast_exist = browser.waitForExist('.toast', 5000);

  if (close_toast.value) {
    close_toast.click();
    browser.waitUntil(function() {
      return close_toast.waitForExist(5000, true);
    }, 5000, 'expecte toast to disappear');
  } else if (closeToasts.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < closeToasts.length; i++) {
      closeToasts[i].click();
      browser.waitUntil(() => {
        return !closeToasts[i].isVisible();
      }, 5000, `Close toast ${i} still visible after 5 s`, 1000);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Oops! toast did NOT disappear');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a `preventDuplicates` option. Try setting it to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `preventDuplicates` option. Try setting it to `true`.

Other options to check out.

```
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": true,       // Allow force-closing 
  "newestOnTop": false,      // Keep the oldest one up-front
  "preventDuplicates": true, // Do not allow duplicates to appear
  "showDuration": 300,      // Time it take to show up, 0.3 sec default
  "hideDuration": 1000,     // Time it take to hide, 1 sec default
  "timeOut": 5000,          // Duration it is displayed, 5 sec default
  "extendedTimeOut": 1000   // Time it takes to hide if hovered, 1 sec default
}
```

Checkout their [demo](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html).

Comment: Thanks, but this is for the front end developer's side. I was asking about UI testing using webdriver io. I don't have the ability to change the code to prevent duplication. In addition, it's not necessarily a duplication since on each action you get a toast